# Prove $\{(t^2,t^3) ∈ \Bbb C^2 | t ∈ \Bbb C\}$ is a variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think I may parametrize to get the relation $y^2-x^3$ from the give form of coordinates. And I am attempting to show that the set ${(t^2,t^3) ∈ \Bbb C^2 | t ∈ \Bbb C}$ is the exactly the zero locus of $X={(t^2,t^3) ∈ \Bbb C^2 | t ∈ \Bbb C}$. Let $\left<y^2-x^3\right>=I$, then clearly $X\in Z(I)$.

Which remains to show is that $Z(I)\subseteq X$. I think maybe it can be shown by division algorithm that let $f\in Z(I)$, then $f=z+r$ for some $z\in Z(I)$ and $r$ is a polynomial in a single variable, then we can conclude that $r(x)=0$ for all $x$ or $r(y)=0$ for all $y$ and hence conclude that $f\in Z(I)$. But I have not found such a method to write $f=z+r$.

Could someone please tell me how to deal with that? Any help or reference to some similar questions are appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Arthur Yes! Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove $Z(I)=X$ you need to show that if $x$, $y\in\Bbb C$ and $x^3=y^2$, there is
$t\in\Bbb C$ with $(x,y)=(t^2,t^3)$.

If $x=0$ then $y=0$ and you can take $t=0$.

If $x\ne0$, set $t=y/x$. Then $t^2=y^2/x^2=x^3/x^2=x$ and $t^3=xt=y$.