# Prove that $\{(t^a,t^b) :t\in\Bbb C\}$ is an affine variaty

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

I am stuck on this exercise question: It asks me to prove that $\{(t^a,t^b) :t\in\Bbb C\}$ is an affine variaty by finding a set of polynomial whose zero locus is $\{(t^a,t^b) \}$ as a subset of the complex plane. I did some search of the question and have just found the case that $a=2$ and $b=3$. But I am not clear what is the general rule.

I am thinking about if $y^a-x^b$ is the desired solution because it vanishes in the whole set $\{(t^a,t^b) \}$ and for all $(x,y)$ satisfies 
$y^a=x^b$, we can take 
$t=y^\frac{1}{b}=x^\frac{1}{a}$. But I am not so sure for this. So could someone confirm am I correct?

The technique I am using is founded here [Prove $\{(t^2,t^3) ∈ \Bbb C^2 | t ∈ \Bbb C\}$ is a variety.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382035/prove-t2-t3-%E2%88%88-bbb-c2-t-%E2%88%88-bbb-c-is-a-variety).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how much you know about algebraic geometry.

However, certainly the equation $f = y^{\frac{lcm(a,b)}{b}} - x^{\frac{lcm(a,b)}{a}}$ vanishes on the curve that is image of $t \mapsto (t^a,t^b)$.

You can prove that $f$ is an irreducible polynomial. Any idea about how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a complete begineer, in fact. I do not quite know how does the fact that $f$ is irreducible imply the desired conclusion. May I ask for an explaination? I was just thinking about if $y^a-x^b$ is the desired polynomial, because it vanishes in the whole set $\{t^a-t^b\}$ and for all $(x,y)$ satisfies $y^a=x^b$, we can take $t=y^\frac{1}{b}=x^{\frac{1}{a}}$. But clearly only one of these two polynomials I am thinking about could be the answer, since the zero locus has one-to -one correspondence to radical ideals. So if $y^a-x^b$ is wrong, may I ask for a reason?

Comment: Well, what happens if a and b are both equal to 2?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think if $a,b$ are both 2, then the set is points of the from $(t^2,t^2)$, which is all the points whose x-coordinate and y-coordinate is equal, But if I take the polynomial to be $y^2-x^2=(y+x)(y-x)$, its zero locus is the union of lines $x=y$ and $y=-x$. So the set $(t^2,t^2)$ cannot represent the whole zero locus. Am I correct?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It makes some sense to me that we require the polynomial to be irreducible. But how to prove that irreducible indeed imply the fact and why the polynomial mentioned gcd is irreducible?

Comment: In general, if you have a parametrized plane curve, its equation is an irreducible polynomial. It is a consequence, if you want, that in this case the curve is an irreducible variety. 

To prove that $f$ is indeed irreducible, try to think about the form that a factor could possibly have and try to obtain a contradiction. I do not have a quick one line argument for that.